# Python нумерует пустые строки при копировании

Tags: python, текст

```
with open('C:\\...\\Demos\\first.txt','r') as firstfile, open('C:\\...\\reports\\second.txt','a') as secondfile:
for idx, line in enumerate(firstfile, start=1):
    secondfile.write('{} {}'. format(idx, line))
```

Как можно обойти нумерацию, кроме проверки циклом?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос данные: исходные и результат.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `filter` для `firstfile`:

```
with open('C:\\...\\Demos\\first.txt','r') as firstfile, open('C:\\...\\reports\\second.txt','a') as secondfile:
    for idx, line in enumerate(filter(lambda s: s != '\n' , firstfile), start=1):
        secondfile.write('{} {}'. format(idx, line))
```

Comment: Ещё более красиво можно сделать фильтр так: `filter(None, map(str.strip, firstfile))`, хотя так и строки из пробелов отрежет, не факт, что это нужно автору вопроса )

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - не использовать функцию enumerate, а инкриментировать вручную, проверяя каждую строчку.

```
with open('C:\\...\\Demos\\first.txt','r') as firstfile, open('C:\\...\\reports\\second.txt','a') as secondfile:
idx = 1
for line in firstfile:
    if line:
        secondfile.write('{} {}'. format(idx, line))
        idx += 1
```